# CarouselView.FormsPlugin get index of specific page

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, itemssource

I'm using [Carousel View by alexrainman](https://github.com/alexrainman/CarouselView) for creating custom wizard.

I need to get index of specific page by its type (I don't know exactly which index would that page have).

Something like this:

```cs
var indexAdvanced = MyCarouselView.GetIndex<ContentView>(typeof(AdditionalDefectParametersContentView));
```

but of course, this code doesn't work. While creating this question, I've got an idea with using `CarouselView`'s `ItemsSource`. How to do it properly? TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the way, I've already found an answer. >_<

The resulting code is:

```cs
// My CarouselView consists of ContentViews
_indexAdvanced = MyCarouselView.ItemsSource.Cast<ContentView>().
                 IndexOf(view => view is AdditionalDefectParametersContentView);
```

So it works!

Don't know what should I do: delete this question or leave? Maybe It would be useful for somebody, so I'll leave it for now.